# What is the Galois group of $27x^8 - 72x^4 - 16$ over the rationals?

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory

Consider the polynomial $f = 27x^8 - 72x^4 - 16$. My question is: what is the Galois group of the splitting field of $f$ over the rational numbers?

When I tried to calculate this, I found that there are $32$ elements of the Galois group, but Sage and Magma both say that there are only $16$ elements. I struggle, however, to see why this is the case because this example is rather subtle. Any suggestions / corrections would be most welcome.

**What I've done so far:**

I've found that the $8$ roots of $f$ are as follows:
$$\pm \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3}}\sqrt[4]{3 \pm 2 \sqrt{3}}, \, \, \, \,\,\,\,\, \pm i \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3}}\sqrt[4]{3 \pm 2 \sqrt{3}}.  $$

An automorphism of $K$ is determined by where it sends the two elements $\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3}}\sqrt[4]{3 + 2 \sqrt{3}}$ and $\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3}}\sqrt[4]{3 - 2 \sqrt{3}}$. Further, these two elements, which I will call $A$ and $B$ respectively, satisfy the following algebraic relation with $\mathbf{Q}$-coefficients:
$$ A^4 B^4 = -\dfrac{4}{3}.$$

This means that if $A$ is sent to an element with a $+$ sign underneath the $4^{\rm{th}}$ root, then $B$ is sent to an element with a $-$ sign underneath the $4^{\rm{th}}$ root, and vice versa. Because if both their images have the *same* sign under the $4^{\rm{th}}$ root, when we take the fourth power and multiply them, we won't get a rational number, so the above algebraic relation won't hold anymore.

**The upshot**:

There are $8$ possible choices to send $A$ to. For each of those, there are $4$ choices for $B$, since given the algebraic relation written above, $A$ and $B$ are sent to numbers with *opposite signs* under the $4^{\rm{th}}$ root, and there are $4$ of these. This means that there are $8 \cdot 4 = 32$ automorphisms. *But this is wrong!* There are only $16$ automorphisms.

I think there is another more elusive algebraic relation these numbers have to satisfy, which constrains the automorphism group to be half as small as expected. But I struggle to find what this other algebraic relation is. If anyone could share an algebraic relation that I'm missing here / share some suggestions for how to move forward, that would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: I don't think the polynomial is normal.

Comment: I'm taking its splitting field, so I don't think that matters.

Comment: sure just wanted to mention it :)

Comment: Please check the roots you have calculated. We have $x^4=(12+8\sqrt {3})/9,-(8\sqrt {3}-12)/9$ and hence the roots are $x=\pm\sqrt[4]{(12+8\sqrt{3})/9},\pm i\sqrt[4]{(12+8\sqrt{3})/9},\pm((1\pm i) /\sqrt{2})\sqrt[4]{(8\sqrt{3}-12)/9}$.

Comment: let $R(x) = x^2 - 72/27 x - 16/27$ so $P(x) = R(x^4)$. Roots of $R$ satisfy $r_1 r_2 = -16/27$. Roots of $P$ will be $\sqrt[4]{r_{1,2}}$. Usually $\sqrt[4]{n}$ has Galois group D_4 (size 8) so it makes sense we have two copies of D_4 (size 16) that can be swapped around.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I got those same roots from Wolfram Alpha as well, I've just rearranged them to this form.

Comment: @river That's interesting - what are $R(x)$ and $P(x)$ in this context? (I.e: what connection do they have to the polynomial $f(x)$ in the question?)

Comment: Let $a$ be the real and positive root. Then it is easily seen that the splitting field must contain $a, ai$ and hence $i$. But $a$ is real and hence $i\notin\mathbb{Q} (a) $. Then $\mathbb {Q} (a, i) $ is of degree $16$ over $\mathbb {Q} $. However I doubt if this is indeed the splitting field of the polynomial. I am somehow not able to show that the other roots lie in $\mathbb {Q} (a, i) $.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The roots are easily found to be $$\pm\sqrt[4]{\frac{4(3+2\sqrt{3})}{9}}=\pm a\text{ (say)} ,\\ \pm i \sqrt[4]{\frac{4(3+2\sqrt{3})}{9}},\\ \pm(1\pm i) \sqrt[4]{\frac{2\sqrt{3}-3}{9}}=\pm(1\pm i) b\text{ (say)} $$ with $a, b$ being positive real numbers.

The given polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb {Q} $ and hence $[\mathbb {Q} (a):\mathbb {Q}] =8$. The splitting field $L$ of the polynomial contains $a, ai$ and hence $i\in L$. But $i\notin\mathbb {Q} (a) $ and hence $[\mathbb {Q} (a, i) :\mathbb {Q}] =16$.

It can be proved with some effort that $L=\mathbb {Q} (a, i) $ is the splitting field of the polynomial and hence the Galois group is of order $16$.

We can note that $$ab=\frac{\sqrt[4]{12}}{3}=\frac{c}{3}\text { (say)} $$ and next we show that $c\in L$. Since $c$ is real we have in fact $c\in\mathbb {Q} (a) $. We can observe that $$c^2=2\sqrt{3}=\frac{9a^4-12} {4}\in\mathbb {Q} (a) $$ and
\begin{align}
9a^4&=4c^2+12\notag\\
&=4c^2+c^4\notag\\
&=c^2(c^2+4)\notag\\
&=c^2(4+2\sqrt{3})\notag\\
&=c^2(1+\sqrt{3})^2\notag
\end{align}
This implies $$3a^2=c(1+\sqrt{3})$$ ie $$c=\frac{6a^2}{2+c^2}\in \mathbb {Q} (a) $$ It now follows that $b=c/(3a)\in\mathbb{Q } (a) \subset L$ and $L$ is the desired splitting field.

The Galois group is $D_{16}$ (dihedral group of order $16$) as explained in another answer.

---

Based on some calculations in another answer here by user dan_fulea one can check that $a/b=1+\sqrt{3}$ which obviously lies in $\mathbb {Q} (a) $. Perhaps checking ratios instead of product of conjugates also helps.

Comment: Really nice! +1

Comment: @river: I was really annoyed as I just could not figure this mystery of $c=\sqrt[4]{12}$, but after a good sleep I understood that we can write $12+8\sqrt {3}$ as $c^4+4c^2$ which makes it a square using $4+2\sqrt{3}=(1+\sqrt{3})^2$. Algebra of surds is really messy and tricky.

Comment: Yes, the check of the value for $a/b$ is immediate from the above, start with $$ab=\frac 13c=\frac 13\cdot\frac{6a^2}{2+c^2}=\frac{2a^2}{2+2\sqrt 3}\ ,$$so$$\frac ba=\frac{2}{2+2\sqrt 3}=\frac 1{1+\sqrt 3} \ .$$ Taking the product $ab$ makes sense, since it is a kind of "building a norm" like in $N_{\Bbb Q(\sqrt 3):\Bbb Q}(\ (3\pm 2\sqrt 3)\ )=(3+  2\sqrt 3)(3- 2\sqrt 3)$... +1

Comment: Wonderful! The $a/b= 1 + \sqrt{3}$ identity was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

First for intuition let us graph the roots of the polynomial:

[image]

This suggests the following automorphisms:

- $\sigma : z \mapsto \bar{z}$ (flip vertically)
- $\tau : z \mapsto -z$ (flip horizontally)
- $\lambda : z \mapsto i z$ (rotation by 90 degrees)
- $\omega : \sqrt{3} \mapsto - \sqrt{3}$ (mysterious automorphism that swaps the inner wheel with the outer points)

We can label the outer roots $r1$ to $r4$ and the inner roots $r5$ to $r7$ we can then come up with the following permutation representations:

- $\sigma = (2\,4)(5\,8)(6\,7)$
- $\tau = (1\,3)(5\,6)(7\,8)$
- $\lambda = (1\,2\,3\,4)(5\,6\,7\,8)$
- $\omega = (2\,8)(3\,7)(4\,6)(1\,5)$ (we do not know this yet, this is calculated later)

and GAP software can recognize this group as `D16`:

```
G := Group(
 (2,4)(5,8)(6,7),
 (1,3)(5,6)(7,8),
 (1,2,3,4)(5,6,7,8),
 (1,5)(2,8)(3,7)(4,6)
 );
Order(G);
StructureDescription(G);
```

---

To know that the order of the Galois group is 16 we calculate the degree of the splitting field. The splitting field is $$L = \mathbb Q(r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4,r_5,r_7,r_6,r_7,r_8)$$ but we have seen that $r_1$ can be mapped to any of the roots $r_2,r_3,r_4$ by our simple transformations, same with $r_5$ so $L = \mathbb Q(i,r_1,r_5)$ we also have (by raising $r_1$ to the 4th power) $\sqrt{3}$ in our field $L = \mathbb Q(i,\sqrt{3},r_1,r_5)$.

Now you can calculate $r_1 r_5 = 2 \sqrt[4]{\frac{-1}{27}}$ so  $L = \mathbb Q(i,\sqrt{3},r_1,\sqrt[4]{\frac{-1}{27}}) = \mathbb Q(i,\sqrt[4]{-3},r_1)$

Over $\mathbb Q$, $i$ has degree 2. Over $\mathbb Q(i)$, $\sqrt[4]{-3}$ has degree 4 and over $\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt[4]{-3})$ adjoining $r_1$ is a simple quadratic extension. so $[\mathbb Q:L] = 2 \cdot 4 \cdot 2 = 16$.

By watching the effect of $r \mapsto 2 \sqrt[4]{-\frac{1}{27}}/r$ on roots $r_1$ to $r_4$ you can find the exact permutation representation of $\omega$.

Comment: $r_1$ is of degree $8$ over $\mathbb{Q} $ and $i$ is not in $\mathbb{Q} (r_1)$ so $F=\mathbb{Q} (i, r_1)$ is of degree $16$ over $\mathbb{Q} $. Your order calculation implies that $\sqrt[4]{-3}=\sqrt[4]{12}/(\pm(1\pm i) )$ lies in $F$. And this is same $\sqrt[4]{12}\in \mathbb {Q} (r_1)$. I really could not convince myself of this. Is there any way to do this explicitly?

Comment: It is true that r_1 is deg 8 over Q, but why do you say that?

Comment: PARI/GP also evaluates the group of order 16,but somehow getting an splitting field of order 16 seems a bit tricky.

Comment: Thank you! The visual description of the automorphisms was very helpful. Appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 1):

We have two algebraic descriptions for $A,B$ in the OP, from their special writing we extract some "obvious" number field containing them, then the OP exhibits for this field a number of Galois morphisms, bigger than expected...

The solution below constructs - assisted by sage - a tower of fields ending with a field of degree $16$ where all the roots of the given polynomial  $f = 27x^8 - 72x^4 - 16$ live in. The reader in hurry may please skip to the description of this tower and ignore the pieces of sage code that lead to its construction.

---

*$(1)$ Sage confirmation of the order of the Galois group.*

Let us ask for the structure of all involved objects using `sage`.

```
sage: R.<X> = PolynomialRing(QQ)
sage: f = 27*X^8 - 72*X^4 - 16
sage: K.<A> = NumberField(f)
sage: G.<s> = K.galois_group()
sage: G
Galois group of Galois closure in s of Number Field in A 
    with defining polynomial 27*X^8 - 72*X^4 - 16
sage: G.order()
16
sage: G.structure_description()
'QD16'
sage: A.minpoly()
x^8 - 8/3*x^4 - 16/27
sage: A^4
A^4
sage: H.<B> = K.galois_closure()
sage: B.minpoly().degree()
16
sage: f.splitting_field(names='B').degree()
16
```

So all the ways to construct the splitting field for $f$ lead to a Galois extension of $\Bbb Q$ of degree $16$. I will denote this field by $C=$`K16`$=K_{16}$. The field $L=K_8=\Bbb Q[x]/(f)$ with elements polynomials modulo $f$ has some, but not all roots of $f$, and $C$ is the  Galois closure of $L$. Let us consider subfields, and count them first.

```
R.<X> = PolynomialRing(QQ)
f = 27*X^8 - 72*X^4 - 16
K8.<A> = NumberField(f)
L = K8
C.<B> = L.galois_closure()

for k in [2, 4, 8]:
    print(f'L = K8 has {len(L.subfields(degree=k))} subfield(s) of degree {k}')

for k in [2, 4, 8]:
    print(f'C = K16 has {len(C.subfields(degree=k))} subfield(s) of degree {k}')
```

We copy+paste the code into the sage interpreter, and obtain:

```
L = K8 has 1 subfield(s) of degree 2
L = K8 has 1 subfield(s) of degree 4
L = K8 has 1 subfield(s) of degree 8

C = K16 has 3 subfield(s) of degree 2
C = K16 has 5 subfield(s) of degree 4
C = K16 has 5 subfield(s) of degree 8
```

Subfields of this field are denoted using degrees as suffix, respectively sub index in a similar way. There will be no confusion since...

*$(2)$ tower of subfields of $L=K_8$.*

Which is that subfield of $L=K_8$ of degree $2$ over the rationals?

```
sage: L.subfields(degree=2)
[
(Number Field in A0 with defining polynomial X^2 - 2*X - 11, Ring morphism:
  From: Number Field in A0 with defining polynomial X^2 - 2*X - 11
  To:   Number Field in A with defining polynomial 27*X^8 - 72*X^4 - 16
  Defn: A0 |--> -9/4*A^4 + 4, None)
]
```

Of course, we need only the field part of the first and only subfield $K_2$ above, and in fact from this field only the discriminant, which is...

```
sage: L.subfields(degree=2)[0][0].discriminant()
12
```

So a simpler way to construct this subfield $K_2$ of $L=K_8$ is:
$$
K_2=\Bbb Q(\sqrt3)\ .
$$
Then the one subfield of $L=K_8$ of degree $4$ over $\Bbb Q$ has defining polynomial over $\Bbb Q$ that splits in two quadratic factors over $K_2$...

```
sage: K2.<s> = QuadraticField(3, embedding=1.732)
sage: K2
Number Field in s with defining polynomial x^2 - 3 with s = 1.732050807568878?
sage: s.complex_embedding()
-1.73205080756888
sage: s.complex_embeddings()
[-1.73205080756888, 1.73205080756888]

sage: RK2.<Y> = PolynomialRing(K2)
sage: f4 = L.subfields(degree=4)[0][0].defining_polynomial()
sage: f4
X^4 + 2*X^3 - 10*X - 11
sage: f4(Y).factor()
(Y^2 + (-s + 1)*Y - 2*s + 1) * (Y^2 + (s + 1)*Y + 2*s + 1)

sage: for fact, mul in f4(Y).factor():
....:     print(fact, 'has discriminant', fact.discriminant().factor())
....: 
Y^2 + (-s + 1)*Y - 2*s + 1 has discriminant (-s + 2) * s^3 * (s + 1)^2
Y^2 + (s + 1)*Y + 2*s + 1 has discriminant (s - 2) * s^3 * (s + 1)^2

sage: ( s*(2-s) ).minpoly()
x^2 + 6*x - 3
```

So it is natural to construct $K_4$ as the field
$$K_4=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{\sqrt3(2-\sqrt 3)})=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2\sqrt3-3})\ ,
$$
where we always pick (when we can) square roots in "the" complex plane $\Bbb C$ to be on the positive real axis.

```
sage: K4.<t> = NumberField(X^4 + 6*X^2 -3, embedding=0.68125)
sage: K4
Number Field in t with defining polynomial X^4 + 6*X^2 - 3 with t = 0.6812500386332133?
sage: RK4.<Z> = PolynomialRing(K4)
sage: f(Z).factor()
(27) * (Z^2 - 1/3*t^3 - 7/3*t) * (Z^2 + 1/3*t^3 + 7/3*t) * (Z^4 + 4/9*t^2)

sage: for fact, mul in f(Z).factor():
....:     print(f'{fact} has the roots {fact.roots(ring=QQbar, multiplicities=0)}')
....: 
Z^2 - 1/3*t^3 - 7/3*t has the roots [-1.301911353059394?, 
                                      1.301911353059394?]
Z^2 + 1/3*t^3 + 7/3*t has the roots [-1.301911353059394?*I,
                                      1.301911353059394?*I]
Z^4 + 4/9*t^2 has the roots [-0.4765326286951095? - 0.4765326286951095?*I,
                             -0.4765326286951095? + 0.4765326286951095?*I,
                              0.4765326286951095? - 0.4765326286951095?*I,
                              0.4765326286951095? + 0.4765326286951095?*I]
```

The results were manually rearranged. The first factor has real root(s) only, so we use one such root to have an instance of $L=K_8$, let it be
the (positive) square root of
$$
\frac 13(t^3+7t)=\frac t3(t^2+7)=\frac t3(2\sqrt 3+4)=\frac 23(2+\sqrt 3)t=\color{blue}{\frac 23(2+\sqrt 3)(2\sqrt 3-3)^{1/2}}\ .
$$
It turns out, that this root is $A$, the number from the OP,
$$
A
=
\sqrt{\frac 23}\cdot (3+2\sqrt 3)^{1/4}
=
\sqrt{\color{blue}{\frac 23(2+\sqrt 3)(2\sqrt 3-3)^{1/2}}}
\ .
$$
(To see the equality, simplify with $\sqrt {2/3}$, then raise to the fourth power, and check $3+2\sqrt 3=(2+\sqrt 3)^2(2\sqrt 3-3)$.)

*$(3)$ Let us adjoin $i=\sqrt{-1}$ to $L=K_8$...*

*A posteriori*, if that Galois degree $16$ is indeed valid, we need only a further quadratic extension of $L=K_8$ to get its Galois closure $C=K_{16}$.
So which "simple" algebraic number should be adjoined? To "guess" such a number, we simply ask sage for the subfields of degree two inside the pretended closure `K16`.

```
sage: for _ in K16.subfields(degree=2):
....:     print(_[0].discriminant().factor())
....: 
-1 * 2^2
2^2 * 3
-1 * 3
```

We already know about $\sqrt 3$ being inside $L=K_8$, so let us adjoin $i=\sqrt {-1}$ (and/or equivalently $\sqrt{-3}$). Using the two algebraic numbers $A,B$ from the OP we have
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
A &= 
\underbrace{
\sqrt{\frac 23}\cdot (2\sqrt 3+3)^{1/4}
}_
{\in\Bbb R_{>0}}
\in L\subset L(i)
\ ,
\\
B &:=
\underbrace{
\sqrt{\frac 23}\cdot (2\sqrt 3-3)^{1/4}
}_
{\in\Bbb R_{>0}}
\cdot(-1)^{1/4}\overset{\color{red}?}\in L(i)\ ,
\\[3mm]
&\qquad\text{ and compute in $\bar{\Bbb Q}$, in fact only in $L(i,\sqrt 2)$...}\\[3mm]
\frac AB
&=
\frac{(2\sqrt 3+3)^{1/4}}{(2\sqrt 3-3)^{1/4}}\cdot\frac 1{(-1)^{1/4}}
\\
&=
\frac
{(2\sqrt 3+3)^{1/4}(2\sqrt 3+3)^{1/4}}
{(2\sqrt 3-3)^{1/4}}\cdot\frac 1{(-1)^{1/4}}
\\
&=
\frac{(2\sqrt 3+3)^{1/2}}
{(12-9)^{1/4}}\cdot\frac 1{(-1)^{1/4}}
\\
&=
\frac{(2+\sqrt 3)^{1/2}\cdot (\sqrt 3)^{1/2}}
{3^{1/4}}\cdot\frac 1{(-1)^{1/4}}
\\
&=
\frac
{(2+\sqrt 3)^{1/2}}
{\frac 1{\sqrt 2}(1+i)}
\\
&=
\frac
{(4+2\sqrt 3)^{1/2}}
{1+i}
\\
&=
\frac
{1+\sqrt 3}
{1+i}
\in L(i)
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The above shows that we have  $A,B\in L(i)$, so $C=L(i)$ is indeed the Galois closure of $L$.

$\square$

---

*$(4)$ A tower of fields:*

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
L(i, \sqrt 2) @. \ni A,B,(-1)^{1/4}\\
@AA:2A\\
L(i)=C=K_{16} @. \ni A,B\\
@AA:2A\\
L=K_8=\Bbb Q(A) @.\ni A\\
@AA:2A\\
K_4=\Bbb Q(A^2) @.\ni A^2=\frac 23(2\sqrt 3+3)^{1/2}\\
@AA:2A\\
K_2=\Bbb Q(\sqrt 3) \\
@AA:2A\\
\Bbb Q
\end{CD}

---

*$(5)$ Alternative solution:*

One can (forget all the above computations, and) construct the numbers $A,B$ from the OP as elements in $\bar{\Bbb Q}=$`QQbar`, then ask for the minimal polynomial of $A/B$, and see that it is in the field generated by $A$. This is the solution that is typed without effort, and the reader needs to invest its effort to join the darts in the puzzle.

```
sage: A = QQbar( sqrt(2/3) * (3 + 2*sqrt(3))^(1/4) )
sage: B = QQbar( sqrt(2/3) * (3 - 2*sqrt(3))^(1/4) )
sage: (A/B).minpoly()
x^4 - 2*x^3 + 2*x^2 + 2*x + 1

sage: var('x');
sage: solve((B/A).minpoly()(x) == 0, x)
[x == -1/2*sqrt( 6*I) - 1/2*I - 1/2,
 x ==  1/2*sqrt( 6*I) - 1/2*I - 1/2,
 x == -1/2*sqrt(-6*I) + 1/2*I - 1/2,
 x ==  1/2*sqrt(-6*I) + 1/2*I - 1/2]
```

Let $L$ be the field $L=\Bbb Q(A)$, and let us adjoin $i=\sqrt{-1}$ to it.
We look at the similarity in the formulas for $A$ and $B$, and try to compute $A/B$. This is best done by asking for the minimal polynomial of $A/B$. So $A/B\in \bar{\Bbb Q}$ becomes one or the other of above roots realized in $\Bbb C$, after fixing the corresponding complex embeddings used by sage. The part $\frac 12(\pm 1\pm i)$ of the root is in $L(i)$, what about the rest? Well, after moving the $\sqrt 3\in \Bbb Q(A)=L$ out of $\sqrt{\pm 6i}$, and possibly also $\sqrt{-1}\in L(i)$, we have to fight against $\sqrt{2i}$. Which is $(1-i)\in L(i)$.

So $B$ has a "hidden" algebraic dependency in terms of the powers of $A$, extracted from the fact that $A/B$ is an algebraic number of degree four over $\Bbb Q$ living in $\Bbb Q(A)$.

---

*$(6)$ Where did the OP fail to count correctly?*

We can write down all eight roots as follows, they build a list $R$:

```
u8 = QQbar( (1+i)/sqrt(2) )
v = QQbar( sqrt(2/3) * (2*sqrt(3) + 3)^(1/4) )
w = QQbar( sqrt(2/3) * (2*sqrt(3) - 3)^(1/4) )

R = [u8^k*v for k in [0, 2, 4, 6]] + [u8^k*w for k in [1, 3, 5, 7]]
```

Now we fix the image of $A$, one of the choices, as described in the OP. Which are the four $=8/2$ "good" choices for the images of $B$ from the OP? We test all possible images, possibly an insufficient path, but necessarily we should fix the minimal polynomial of $A/B$...

```
sage: for b in R:
....:     print(f'a/b = {a/b} with minimal polynomial {(a/b).minpoly()}')
....: 
a/b = 1.000000000000000? with minimal polynomial x - 1
a/b = 0.?e-19 - 1.000000000000000?*I with minimal polynomial x^2 + 1
a/b = -1.000000000000000? + 0.?e-18*I with minimal polynomial x + 1
a/b = 0.?e-18 + 1.000000000000000?*I with minimal polynomial x^2 + 1
a/b = 1.366025403784439? - 1.366025403784439?*I with minimal polynomial x^4 - 2*x^3 + 2*x^2 + 2*x + 1
a/b = -1.366025403784439? - 1.366025403784439?*I with minimal polynomial x^4 + 2*x^3 + 2*x^2 - 2*x + 1
a/b = -1.366025403784439? + 1.366025403784439?*I with minimal polynomial x^4 + 2*x^3 + 2*x^2 - 2*x + 1
a/b = 1.366025403784439? + 1.366025403784439?*I with minimal polynomial x^4 - 2*x^3 + 2*x^2 + 2*x + 1
```

There are thus only two choices! (The $a$ was taken to be $A$. We know $B$ is one of the values making the minimal  polynomial of $A/B$ be equal to
$x^{4} - 2 x^{3} + 2 x^{2} + 2 x + 1
$. Now we let $b$ take all possible values in $R$. One good value is $b=B$ corresponding to the identity Galois morphism. And there is only one other good chance!)

Comment: This is a fairly long answer, as written, i started it longer time ago trying to explicitly address the question(s) and the method of counting from the OP. At some point editing was frozen, could continue only today.

Comment: +1. From your answer i can see that the ratio of roots $A/B$ can work for my strategy also. If $a, b$ are as in my answer then $a/b=\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{3}}=1+\sqrt{3}$ which clearly lies in $\mathbb{Q} (a) $. This is somewhat easier than figuring out that $ab\in\mathbb{Q} (a) $.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write such a thorough answer! The Sage code was very helpful; I learned a lot from your explanations.

Comment: The computational techniques here will be a great help in future!