# How to check if splitting fields of different polynomials share a subfield?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

First, some context: I'm working through the section on galois theory in Lang's *Algebra* in preparation for my qual. Exercise $1$ part $(j)$ asks us to compute the galois group of $(x^2 - 2)(x^2 - 3)(x^2 - 5)(x^2 - 7)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Since each irreducible factor is of degree $2$, and the fields are obviously not *equal*, their pairwise intersections are all $\mathbb{Q}$ (since there's no room for the intersection to be anything else). This means we can apply the theorem on galois groups of composita to get the answer $C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2$.

However, I'm not sure how I would go about showing this in a more complicated example.

For instance, the galois group of $(x^2 + 3)(x^2 + x + 1)$ is just $C_2$, since $\mathbb{Q}\left ( \sqrt{-3} \right ) = \mathbb{Q}(\omega)$ (in $\mathbb{C}$, say). It's extremely non-obvious (at least to me) that these polynomials would be related, and if I didn't happen to know $\omega = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{-3}}{2}$ is a cube root of unity, I would have guessed that this polynomial had galois group $C_2 \times C_2$ (by an argument analogous to the previous one).

So the question, then:

> If I'm asked to compute the galois group of a polynomial that factors into irreducibles as $f_1 f_2 \cdots f_n$, what are some strategies for checking that the roots don't "interact"? That is, if $E_j$ is the splitting field of $f_j$, how can we be sure that $E_i \cap E_j = \mathbb{Q}$? Conversely, if the roots *do* interact, is there a way of detecting this?

Thanks in advance! ^_^

Comment: In general this is a difficult problem involving algebraic number theory. A variant of the problem is: given two algebraic numbers $\alpha, \beta $ determine if $\beta\in\mathbb {Q} (\alpha) $.

Comment: For the example $(x^2+3)(x^2+x+1)$ you can complete the square of second factor to write is as $(1/4)((2x+1)^2+3)=(1/4)(y^2+3)$ if $y=2x+1$ and hence the splitting field of one factor serves as a splitting field of the entire polynomial.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh -- I'm relieved to hear this is difficult, rather than me being slow. Do you know of any heuristics, or tricks that work in low degrees? Thanks for the completing the square example, by the way! That's a cute way of seeing these polynomials are related, and I would have never thought to try that.

Comment: I am no expert in this area but I know a few tricks which can be used by novices like me. For example if $\alpha$ is of degree $m$ and $\beta$ of degree $n$ and $n$ does not divide $m$ then we have $\beta\notin\mathbb {Q} (\alpha) $. Another trick is to assume the inclusion and derive some contradiction. Some general theorems can help. Eg if $p$ is an odd prime then $\mathbb {Q} (e^{2\pi i/p}) $ has a unique quadratic subfield  $\mathbb {Q} (\sqrt{(-1)^{(p-1)/2}p}) $. And finally if an equation has an abelian galois group then the roots lie in some cyclotomic extension.

Comment: And often the real challenge is to prove the inclusion when it is true. Sometimes we are able to find the relation between $\alpha, \beta$ by trial-error, but in general this is really difficult to figure out.

Comment: It's a good question, but a bad title. $a$ and $b$ are algebraically independent means there's no nonzero polynomial $p(x,y)$ with integer coefficients such that $p(a,b)=0$. So no root of a polynomial with integer coefficients can ever be algebraically independent of anything.

Comment: Of course you can know which quadratic field extension is relevant using the discriminant. So this solves the problem for the degree 2 situation.

For more complex situations you may look into factorization mod, for example notice that x^2-7 does not factorize mod y^2-5, but x^2+x+1 does factorize mod y^2+3 (and vice versa).

Comment: You may have a look at [this recent answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4207328/72031) where it took me quite some time to figure out a relation of the form $\beta\in\mathbb {Q} (\alpha) $. Such relations are really important to find the splitting field and then figure out the Galois group.

Comment: So, you've taken out "algebraically dependent", and that's good, but you've put in "field dependent", and there's no such thing. I'm afraid the condition that interests you can't be expressed in two words.

Comment: @GerryMyerson -- I didn't edit the title, somebody else did. I had never heard of "Field Dependent" either, but I assumed this was my own ignorance and left it. I'll come up with a better title.

Comment: My apologies, Halla, I should have read more carefully.

Comment: @GerryMyerson -- no offense was taken ^_^