# Question about a Galois group

Tags: number-theory, field-theory

I am working on a problem which seems to be troubling me quite a lot. This is how it goes:
Let $\alpha=\sqrt{\frac{2\sqrt{3}-3}{3}}$ and $\beta=\sqrt{\frac{2\alpha}{\sqrt{3}}}$. It is easy to show that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are $3x^4+6x^2-1$ and $27x^8+72x^4-16$, respectively. One can see that $\mathbb{Q}(\beta,i)$ contains "the" splitting field of $3x^4+6x^2-1$. *The part I am having trouble with is to show that this field also contains "the" splitting field of* $27x^8+72x^4-16$.
I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Is there actually a question about a Galois group? May be even about the Galois group?

Comment: Upvoting, for you have obviously worked quite a bit on the problem. It might be useful for your readers to have the extra pieces (from your responses to Tomás*s answer) in the question body.

Comment: This is really a question about the Galois group. I am trying to first prove that $\mathbb{Q}(E[3])/\mathbb{Q}$ is not an abelian extension, where $E$ is the elliptic curve $y^2=x^3+x$ not admitting CM. Finally, I would like to get a suitable pair $(M,N)$ in Serre's Theorem and thereby conclude that these $N$ and $M$ are dependent on $E$ in this case. The only thing I need help with is the splitting field of $\beta$ is contained in $\mathbb{Q}(\beta,i)$.

Comment: It would be nice to include equation in the title as well because as of now the title looks too generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's check the roots of the equation $27x^8+72x^4-16=0$. Putting $t=x^4$ we get the equation $27t^2+72t-16=0$ with roots $$t=\frac{-12\pm8\sqrt{3}}{9}=\beta^4,-\frac{16}{27\beta^4}$$ Hence the roots of original equation are given by $$x=\pm\beta, \pm i\beta, \pm\frac{1\pm i}{\beta}\sqrt[4]{\frac{4}{27}}$$ so our job is done if we can show that $\sqrt[4]{4/27}\in\mathbb{Q}(\beta,i)$.

We can in fact show that $\sqrt[4]{4/27}\in \mathbb{Q} (\beta) $ or equivalently $a=\sqrt[4]{12}\in\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$. We note that $$a^2=2\sqrt{3}=\frac{9\beta^4+12}{4}$$ or
\begin{align}
9\beta^4&=4a^2-12\notag\\
&=a^2(4-a^2)\notag\\
&=a^2(4-2\sqrt{3})\notag\\
&=a^2(\sqrt{3}-1)^2\notag
\end{align}
and then $$3\beta^2=a(\sqrt{3}-1)$$ Note that $\sqrt{3}=(9\beta^4+12)/8\in\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$ and hence by above equation $a\in\mathbb{Q} (\beta) $.

---

While typing my answer I remembered [a previous answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4207328/72031) which contained similar calculation. Perhaps the equation there is related to the one given here via some simple substitution.

Comment: I think you have a typo. It should be $x=\pm \beta,\pm i\beta, \pm \frac{1\pm i}{\beta}\sqrt[4]{\frac{16}{27}}$.

Comment: @ShyamalSayak: The roots of $x^4=-1$ are $\pm(1\pm i) /\sqrt{2}$ so the radical should have $4/27$ under it. There is some cancellation with the $\sqrt{2}$ in denominator.

Comment: I see. That makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

It may be of help to look at the roots of $27x^8 +72x^4 -16$. In order to compute the roots you can think of it as a quadratic polynomial via a change of variables $y = x^4$.

Comment: This looks like a comment.  Please wait until you can post comments.

Comment: I have computed all the roots of both the minimal polynomials. It is not helping. The whole thing boils down to showing that $\sqrt[4]{\frac{-1}{3}}\in \mathbb{Q}(\beta,i)$. Proving this should complete my proof.

Comment: I would suggest to compute them again because the roots of the polynomial are 

1) $\pm i \beta $

2) $\pm \beta$ 

All of them belonging to the field $\mathbb{Q}(\beta,i)$.

Comment: No. There are obviously 4 other roots (the polynomial being a degree 8 polynomial) which are $\pm \frac{2\sqrt{i}}{\sqrt[4]{27}\beta}$ and $\pm \frac{2\sqrt{-i}}{\sqrt[4]{27}\beta}$.